# Bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am trying to make bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails work but I'm having issues.
I followed the instructions on https://github.com/lubieniebieski/bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails

However, when I try to put in these lines

```
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap-datetimepicker';
```

into my boostrap_and_overrdes.css.less file, it says that bootstrap.less and bootstrap-datetimepicker.less can't be found. @import 'twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap' works but when I manually add the bootstrap-datetimepicker.less file from tarruda, it doesn't work because the first line in that is

```
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";
```

and I don't have a variables.less or mixins.less file so things like @whatever and .border-radius do not work.
I installed twitter bootstrap with twitter-bootstrap-rails and I also added the gem for less-rails.

github: https://github.com/ninajlu/videos

Answer (score 0):

You really should read the documentation on the github page more precisely:

or if you're having problems (or using less) require it in your main stylesheet 
     manifest file:

```
 *= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this problem because you are using less, but you are following the instructions for SCSS, which don't work the same way.

The instructions in the page you mentioned explain how to fix your issue by writing the following:

```
*= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

in the application.css file, somewhere before the `*= require_tree .` line.

do this and it will work right away.

In particular there's no need of including any files manually. So you can undo the workaround you tried.

hope this helps,